# Замена значения по трем таблицам

Tags: update, mysql

Доброго времени суток!

Имеются 3 таблицы: price, product и Atable.
`product (id, opisanie ...)` и `tseni(id, tsena_spb , tsena_msk ,...)` связанны по id.

Atable имеет 2  столбца:  price и opisanie.

Задача  заменить  `tseni.tsena_spb` и `tsena_msk` на `Atable.price`, если `product.opisanie = Atable.opisanie;`.

Запросом

```
 select * from (select produkt.opisanie , Atable.price from produkt left join Atable on produkt.opisanie like Atable.desk)t1 where t1.price is not null;
```

я получил совпадения.

Столкнулся со сложностью - не обновляет (то ли запрос составил неверно, то ли не дождался выполнения (хотя вряд ли)):

```
update tseni, Atable2, produkt  set tseni.tsena_spb = Atable2.price and tseni.tsena_msk = Atable2.price  where produkt.opisanie = Atable2.desk;
```

`Atable2` - это результат вышеприведенной выборки.

Не отходя от темы:

```
mysql> select * from (select produkt.opisanie , Atable.price from produkt left join Atable on produkt.opisanie like Atable.desk)t1 where t1.price is not null;
всего 380 rows

mysql> select * from (select produkt.opisanie , Atable.price from produkt left join Atable on SOUNDEX(produkt.opisanie) = SOUNDEX(Atable.desk))t1 where t1.price is not null
836 rows in set (43.22 sec)
```

При использовании функции `soundex()` по двум переменных полученно 836 результатов. 
Насколько рационально это использовать, если `Atable.opisanie` в виде:

> Плитка керамическая настенная TREASURE
> KASHMIR 25x75 см

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил вопрос. 
Создал новую таблицу Articles_l

```
<code>
 create table Article_l  select * from (select produkt.id, produkt.opisanie , Atable.price from produkt left join Atable on produkt.opisanie like Atable.desk)t1 where t1.price is not null
</code>
```

Ну и обновил...

```
update tseni, Article_l set tseni.tsena_spb = Article_l.price, tseni.tsena_msk=Article_l.price where tseni.id = Article_l.id;
```